# Error while using csrf

Tags: django

This is my view function

```
@csrf_request
def view_function(request, template_name):
    c = {}
    return return render_to_response(template_name, {'recipe' : objRecipeForm}, c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I also used a {% csrf_token %} in my template

The error I get is `render_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'`

I am kinda new with django so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return return render_to_response(template_name, {'recipe' : objRecipeForm}, c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I don't think this is CSRF fault, first of `return return` is a bit much, one is enough, also you have extra arguments for render_to_response, try like this:

```
@csrf_request
def view_function(request, template_name):
    c = {'recipe' : objRecipeForm}
    return render_to_response(template_name, c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Yes, This was a silly mistake and my tooth ache was killing me.